# Jquery Ajax, mySQL UTF-8

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, utf-8

A have a form on page, the header contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Then I have a script to post ajax data:

```
function submitmessage(id){
$.ajax({ type :"post", 
     data : { newmessage: $('#message_'+id).val(), 
     newfrom: $('#from_'+id).val(), 
     newto: $('#to_'+id).val(), 
     newadid: $('#adid_'+id).val() },
     url : "newcomment.php",
     success: function(){
         ad_sendmessage(id);
         $('#message_'+id).val("");
    }
  });};
```

The PHP file is like this:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    $message=$_POST['newmessage'];
    $from=$_POST['newfrom'];
    $to=$_POST['newto'];
    $adid=$_POST['newadid'];
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '13Sept1983','b2b_test');
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($con,"set names 'utf8'");
    $sql="INSERT INTO Message (Message, MesFrom, MesTo, Adid)
    VALUES ('$message', $from, $to, $adid)";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($con);
}else { }
?>
```

But I still get UTF-8 characters in dataBase as ????

Can anybody help to solve the problem?

Comment: Try ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci in your DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE Message CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci")
```